# Calculating total price of items with increasing price is too slow

Tags: python, algorithm, math, game-development

I'm creating a simple idle game where you buy stuff and the price increases for each item you buy. I have a button that allows the player to buy the maximum amount she can in a single click. This works fine, but calculating the total price is very slow, because I'm doing so in a while loop. How can I simplify this?

```
var accumulatedPrice = 0.0
var maxMultiplier = 0
while accumulatedPrice <= allMyMoney:
    var assetPrice = 4.8
    var priceGrowth = 1.12
    priceGrowth = pow(priceGrowth, asset.currentAmount+maxMultiplier-1)
    assetPrice *= priceGrowth
    accumulatedPrice += assetPrice
    maxMultiplier += 1
```

I simplified my code a bit, and it's not written in any specific language. I'm actually using a big number class to allow for extremely high numbers, but the math is the same as above. It gets slow when the maxMultiplier ends up high.

Comment: How high is high?  Your problem could be simply that infinite precision with very large numbers is slow.

Comment: That is indeed part of the problem, but I was hoping this specific calculation could be done without a while loop somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to understand the problem.
I've tried it with a 64bit maximum integer (`9223372036854775807`) and it took me `2.7418136596679688e-05` seconds.

```
from time import time
import sys

all_money = sys.maxsize
asset_price = 1.8
price_growth = 1.12
next_asset_price = asset_price ** price_growth
amount = 0
start = time()

while all_money > 0:
    if all_money - next_asset_price < 0:
        print(f"Total: {amount}")
        break

    all_money -= next_asset_price
    amount += 1
    next_asset_price = next_asset_price ** price_growth

print(f"\nTotal runtime: {time()-start}")
```

Comment: I know, but maximum integer is way too small for my game. But thanks, just not what I'm looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have this recurrent formula for a sum of costs of **n** items:
**S(n) = S(n-1) + BaseCost*(k^(n-1))**
It can be simplified by extracting **BaseCost**:
**S(n) = BaseCost*(1 + k^1 + k^2 + k^3 + ... + k^(n-1))**
There is a formula for this kind of a finite geometric series:
[image: series formula]
So, our original sum formula can be simplified to:
**S(n) = BaseCost*(1-k^n)/(1-k)**
Using this nonrecurrent formula, you can rewrite your algorithm to a simple calculation.
Given max available sum **Smax** we can do this:
**Smax*(1-k)/BaseCost = 1-k^n**
**n = log_k(1 - Smax*(1-k)/BaseCost)**

I tested it in a spredsheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sZMpmHzcNu6NWw9HJexlIz1onOMh3DdlJYiW548xlgM/edit?usp=sharing